# Custom Template & Rapido Breaks URL Paths

Tags: plone, zope, plone-5.x

### Outline

I have a custom type (Dexterity) called "Gallery Profile", for this type I went into the ZMI (portal_skins/custom), created a new "Page Template" and wrote a custom template for my gallery. The gallery contains a bunch of lower down images and one main image of the owner of the gallery, like a News Item view but a gallery tacked on the bottom.

The customer wants this main image to be published to Facebook when someone hits 'Share' and some more specific info in the title when published.

### Work carried out

Configured a Rapido script to write the 'og:image' meta data etc HTML that is required to get this to work (the default Plone stuff only publishes the sites logo unless you're viewing one Image type).

If I go to test the HTML coming out of Rapido via direct web address it works swimmingly. (site.com/@@rapido/og_share/block/og_share) - I'm on the slightly older version of Rapido hence the non-plural version of block.

### The problem

If you go to my gallery page where we have applied the template, then check the HTML, all of the OG meta data is pointing to the template instead of the current page its on.

This effects queries too (if for example you're using a script to find out what images are within a folder) - it searches /my_template instead of site.com/a_folder/my_template_is_on

In the Rapido Python file I've tried things like:

```
context.content.absolute_url()
context.content.absolute_url_path()
context.request['URL']
context.request['VIRTUAL_URL']
context.request['ACTUAL_URL']
```

... and probably more as I've been at this a while.

If you're not on the custom template, *it works*.

### To Reproduce

- Create a custom template
- Assign it as the default view of a folder or any type.
- In your template put `<div tal:replace="structure python:context.REQUEST"></div>` (just to see the difference)
- In your Rapido try using `context.app.log()` and any of the above
- Refresh your templated folder while checking the logs and the output from the context.REQUEST stuff.
- You will see the differences and how Rapido is having a hard time getting the URL of the page you are on even though its there.

I've always had this problem with Rapido I just tend to work around it but in this particular situation I am stumped.

### So in summary

- Am I being an idiot and missing something obvious?
- Is this possible?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I posted a link to your question in our forum, at https://community.plone.org/t/stack-overflow-custom-template-rapido-breaks-url-paths/4199

Comment: Rapido uses the current subrequest to solve the context, so it behaves nicely with Diazo. How do you insert the Rapido block into the template? Diazo rule or something else?

Comment: @ebrehault Yeah I am using a Diazo rule to insert the Rapido block. Is there other methods to do so?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that bug. I use `context.content.absolute_url()` in my Rapido script and the result is fine (the current content url) even if I used my custom template as a default view for my content or not. If you want to debug, put a pdb here https://github.com/collective/rapido.plone/blob/master/src/rapido/plone/app.py#L136 and see what happens.